# 'Execution target' list on KMM Android studio is empty

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying my hand at Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile, and am trying to run the demo app on an iPhone. I am able to run it easily on the Xcode simulation but can't simulate it on Android Studio, I'm not able to se 'Execution target' list [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogKGI.png)
I can do it on Xcode but No when I try directly on Android Studio, What can I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxucy.png)

I need to select 'Expectation target' but I can't see any option an the list

Comment: in your  `.idea>workspace.xml` file should be configuration element with `type="KmmRunConfiguration"` something like

`<configuration name="iosApp" type="KmmRunConfiguration" factoryName="iOS Application"...`. Could you show it?